# How to recursively loop through files and add data derived from a certain file name in bash without using the find command?

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to bash & awk and am trying to learn how to loop through a few directories and add data from files with a certain name.

Let's say we have the following directories:

```
/scoresA/.scores
/scoresB/.scores
/scoresB/score/.scores
/scoresC/scores.txt
/scoresD/
```

The file `.scores` has scores for each person in the following format:

```
Jacob 6
Joe 7
Kyle 9
```

I want to recurse through these directories, only files with the name `.scores` and add the score for a certain person.

Here is the bash code I wrote to recurse through the files.

```
function runCheck {
    FILE_NAME=".scores"
    CAND=$1
    START_DIR=$PWD
    
    shopt -s dotglob
    for file in "$START_DIR"/**/*
    do
        if [[ $file == *"${FILE_NAME}"* ]]
        then
            # awk script here
        fi
    done
}
```

When I run the function, runCheck, I want to add the score for a given person. So, when I run `runCheck "Jacob"` I want to check every `.scores` file that exists and add his score and print it out. I'm very new to bash and am just trying to learn more, but I was unable to successfully recurse through all the files and total it. If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: The UNIX tool to **find** files is named `find` - see its man page. Don't use all upper case names for non-exported variables to avoid clashes with builtin and exported names. Use `runCheck() {` instead of `function runCheck {` for portability. Declare local variables as such by prefixing them with the word `local`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for your comment. I actually found a way to do it using the `find` command. However, I'm trying to do it without using `find`. I remember one of my professors doing it away, but I have since forgotten. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: `**` needs globstar: `runCheck()( shopt -s globstar; cat **/.scores | awk -v p="$1" '$1==p{s+=$2} END{print s}')`

Comment: @faraaz don't assume your professor really knew what they were doing, based on the  homework questions we see here many of them have no clue how to write shell scripts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to *recurse,* you have to actually do that.

```sh
my_find () {
    local dir=$1
    local pat=$2
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            my_find "$file" "$pat"
        elif [ "${file##*/}" = "$pat" ]; then
            echo "$file"
        fi
    done
}
```

Usage example:

```sh
my_find . .scores | xargs awk 1
```

to run `awk 1` on all `.scores` files in the current directory `.` and its subdirectories.

For comparison, the same with `find` would look like

```sh
find . -type f -name .scores -exec awk 1 {} +
```